# Which exception method should be overriden?

Tags: java

I have an own exception, i.e. InputException.

When it isn't caught, the JVM writes to console the stack trace.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InputException{
    throw new InputException();
}
```

JVM writes to console.

Exception in thread "main" InputException
at test.Main.main(Main.java:8)

How can I change this message, which method of the InputException generates this stackTrace?

Comment: override getMessage()

Comment: throw new InputException("your message here");

Comment: There's no more stacktrace. What do you exepect it to show?

Answer (score 3):

```
throw new InputException("your message here");
```

So you have to create a constructor with string parameter calling super in your exception class:

```
public class InputException extends Exception {
    public InputException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

The message printed on the console is the message returned by the `getMessage()` method returning by default the message passed to the `Throwable` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to change `Exception in thread [threadName] [className] at [codeLine]`.

Instead you may want to catch exception, handle it and output some neat message to console (or logger) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Overload the constructor for `InputException`

```
public InputException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

then use it

```
throw new InputException("an input exception has occurred");
```

Answer (score 1):

JVM internally calls `printStackTrace()` method(Since you didn't override it so `Throwable` class implementation will be called).
Accroding to [Throwable#printStackTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace)

> The first line of output contains the result of the toString() method for this object. Remaining lines represent data previously recorded by the method fillInStackTrace()

If you don't want this representation then you can override `printStackTrace()` method in your custom exception class or else you can pass String message as constructor argument while creating its object.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the `Exception` constructor with the message that should be printed, e.g.

```
public InputException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

And then throw the Exception as follows:

```
throw new InputException("message");
```

Please have a look at the Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String%29) on why we can do this.